# Strange errors in Microsoft SDK using Shobjidl.h

Tags: c++, windows

I want to retrieve the folder of the current user document folder in cpp, so I use `SHGetFolderPath` and include `Shobjidl.h`.

As the result my code does not compile and the following output is generated:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\shobjidl.h(8994): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\shobjidl.h(8994): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\shobjidl.h(8994): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\shobjidl.h(8994): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

The code behind these errors is:

```
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetInt32( 
            /* [in] */ __RPC__in REFPROPERTYKEY key,
            /* [out] */ __RPC__out int *pi) = 0; // <- this line produces compile error
```

What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

I am using Win 7, VS2010 Express.

Answer (score 3):

The header file you need to include for that function is `Shlobj.h`, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not `Shobjidl.h`.  I'd guess that `Shobjidl.h` is likely an internal header file and not meant to be included directly -- it probably depends on other header files already being included before it, which would fix the errors you're seeing.

Comment: I also thied that. The outcome is the same. Compile errors due to errors in `Shobjidl.h`.